# Parent div's height is larger than its child div when using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 3 `divs` wrapped in 2 parent `divs`. All 3 child `divs` have a `div` inside of them **with** an assigned `height`. The problem is, the child `divs` wrapper (the ones with the class name of `content`) get a height of whatever the largest child `div` is.

The emmet version of the HTML hierarchy is as follows: `div>div>(div>div)*3`

How can I get the `div` with the class of `content` to have the same height as its child?

#### JSFiddle

```js
var first = document.getElementById('first');

console.log(first.offsetHeight + ' ' + first.firstElementChild.offsetHeight); // 250 200
// How can I get them both to be 200 automatically?
```

```css
.content {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapperLongInner {
  display: flex;
}
.wrapperShortOuter {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapperShortOuter" style="width: 300px;">
  <div class="wrapperLongInner" style="width: 600px;">
    <div class="content" id="first" style="width: 300px">
      <div style="background-color: turquoise; width: 300px; height: 200px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="second" style="width: 0px;">
      <div style="background-color: burlywood; width: 300px; height: 150px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="third" style="width: 0px;">
      <div style="background-color: yellowgreen; width: 300px; height: 250px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="background-color: red; width:50px; height: 100px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do but the default vertical sizing (`align-items`) in a flex-container is `stretch`.

If you change this to `flex-start` the heights are both 200 as required.

```js
var first = document.getElementById('first');

alert(first.offsetHeight + ' ' + first.firstElementChild.offsetHeight); // 250 200
// How can I get them both to be 200 automatically?
```

```css
.wrapperShortOuter {
  width: 300px;
  background: #000;
}
.wrapperLongInner {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  ;
}
#first {
  width: 300px;
}
#first div {
  background-color: turquoise;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
#second {
  width: 0;
}
#second div {
  background-color: burlywood;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}
#third {
  width: 0;
}
#third div {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
}
#last {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapperShortOuter">
  <div class="wrapperLongInner">
    <div class="content" id="first">
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="second" style="width: 0px;">
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="third" style="width: 0px;">
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="last"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.content {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapperLongInner {
  display: block;
}

.wrapperShortOuter {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Try taking the value for the `display` property to `block`. You'll have to give some feedback if the layout doesn't match the layout you intended.